# How do I check if an integer contains digit 0 and 1 or not?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Say, to check a 4 digit integer.
How do I check whether it contains 0 or 1?

Using digit 1234, it contains 1. Therefore I would have to reject.
Using digit 1023, it contains 0. Therefore I have to reject.
But for digit 2345, it doesn't contain 0 nor 1, so it's not rejected. How do I proceed from there?

I tried to:
divide 10 of my integer,
used if else, and to cin.clear and cin.ignore whenever a digit 0 or 1 is in the integer.

but it doesn't work.

```
cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
cin >> number;

int outputcounter =4;
while(outputcounter!=0)
{
    lastDigit=number%10;
    number=number/10;

    while ( number > 1 )
    {

        if ((lastDigit = 1 )|| (lastDigit = 0 ))
        {
            cin.clear ();
            cin.ignore (100, '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " xx";

        }


    }
```

ahhh I'm so sorry I know this is done very badly. I'm learning on my own (just started this month) and I've tried googling but I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: convert it to a string, check each digit, done

Comment: can you please show us what you've done so far?

Comment: There could be many solution.Please paste your code here.

Comment: done! it is done badly though. I am sorry :(

Comment: `outputcounter` will always be 4, becuase you're intitialising it and never changing it. And then you're asking it to loop until it's 0, which it will never be,

Comment: An integer doesn’t contain digits. The **text representation** of an integer contains digits. So convert it to text and look for whatever you need.

Comment: In the if-statement `lastDigit = 1` **makes** the variable hold the value `1`. Use `lastDigit == 1` to test if it already has that value.

Comment: I don't understand why the close voters haven't retracted their votes now that OP clarified the question with code. In fact a fourth vote came in after the update. How is this still off-topic?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to solve the opposite question. See [this](https://ideone.com/n0kOyk)

Answer (score 4):

Converting to a string will be your easiest solution, though not computationally the most efficient:

```
int number;
...
std::string number_str = std::to_string(number);
if (number_str.find_first_of("01") != std::string::npos) {
    // reject the number
}
```

Comment: You'd have to repeat the `find` - once for 0 and once for 1. `find_first_of` would let you search for both at the same time.

Comment: Great point, edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
            {
            int number;
            cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
           cin >> number;
            int flag = 0;
           while(number != 0){
               int temp = number % 10;
               number = number/10;
                if(temp == 1 || temp == 0){
                    cout<<"rejected";
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0){
                cout<<"Accepted";
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Say `i` contains the integer to check. A return value of 1 means that a 1 or 0 is contained. A zero value means your number doesn't contain a zero or one. I assume `i`is positive (or zero).

```
int checkHasOneOrZero(int i)
{
    int j;

    if (i == 0) return 1; /* i == 0000 */

    while (i > 0) {
        j = i % 10;
        if (j == 0 || j == 1) return 1;
        i = i / 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Exchanged the return values because of Arthur's justified comment

Comment: I'd expect a function called "`checkHasOneOrZero`" to return `1` (which is truethy in C and C++) when the number *does* have a one or zero. Other than that this is a good solution.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It would be better with the return values exchanged. I've been blinded by the fact that 0 and 1 are the "forbidden" values.

Comment: what's wrong with boolean values?

Comment: @Sugar Nothing's wrong with Boolean values. But to be honest, as a C programmer, I didn't know if the Boolean literals in C++ are spelled "true", "True" or "TRUE" (or even different from those possibilities). The code is easy to modify if you prefer Booleans.

Comment: @Ronald it's all-lowercase. Specific boolean redefinition used mostly in some device firmwares written in C or old C++. So it's not really the case for C++. https://wandbox.org for online compiler. Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is based on the code you used

**Use this:** (According to your used code)

```
cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
cin >> number;

int outputcounter =4;
while(outputcounter!=0)
{
    if(number%10==0 || number%10==1)
    {
       cout<<"the number contains 0/1"; 
       break;
    }
    number=number/10; 
        outputcounter--;
}
```

**For variable length number:**

```
cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
cin >> number;

do 
{
    int mod = number%10;
    if(mod==0 || mod==1)
    {
       cout<<"the number contains 0/1"; 
       break;
    }
    number=number/10;
}while(number!=0);
```

Comment: Worth noting that this only works if the integer is exactly 4 digitis - it's not clear from the question if this will always be the case, although the OP's attempt looks that way.

Comment: What if number contain more than 4 digit. Try to make generalize logic. Don't use hard coding.

Comment: @Steve In the first line, He said that it's 4 digit integer and I wants to make the answer which will be most understanding for him as He said he's in early learning stage so I just changed his Code for the result. There are many short and optimal answers available.

Comment: you optimize your code and call `mod` operation once per cycle instead of two

Comment: Done @Sugar , Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Suppose x is your integer.

```
int n= x;
bool has_zero_one = n==0 || n==1;
while(n> 0){
int reminder = n%10;
if(remainder ==0 || remainder ==1) {
has_zero_one = true;
break;
}
n= n/10;
}
if(has_zero_one) cout<< "Yes"<<endl;
else cout<<"No"<<endl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in many fashion.Here is what I would do:

```
 int a=02345;
    while(a)
    {
        if(a%10==0 || a%10==1)
        {cout<<"the number contains 0/1"; break;}
        a/=10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool containsOneOrZero(unsigned int number) {
    if (number == 0) return false; // because "0", you know...
    while (number > 0) {
        auto rem = number % 10;
        number = (int) (number / 10);
        if (rem == 0 || rem == 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Haven't tested this.

Comment: You take the modulo after the division meaning the last digit is not checked. Your function name implies you have the true/false the wrong way round.

Comment: @acraig5075 Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that probably your easiest way is to convert to string and use [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). Please, see the example below:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 1;i<argc;i++){
        int number = atoi(argv[i]);
        std::string str;
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss<<number;
        str = oss.str();
        std::cout<<"number "<<number;
        if (str.find("0") != std::string::npos)
            std::cout<<" contains 0"<<std::endl;
        else
            std::cout<<" does not contain 0"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you enter 0123 it will not work because in the conversion (using `atoi`) the leading 0 will be removed. However, it works if the 0 is in the middle of the number.

Comment: You'd have to call `find` twice, once for 0 and once for 1. Could use `find_first_of` instead.

Comment: Yew, In my example I only look for one of the two proposed digits. Of course [`find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)and [`find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) could be also used.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure on this but you could cast it to a char[] then check every character via a for-loop and if one of them is either 0 or 1 reject them.

```
public bool Check(int pInput)
{
    std::string tempStr = "" + pInput;
    const char* tempChr = tempStr.c_str();

    boolean ret = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < tempStr.length; i++)
    {
        if(tempChr[i] == "0" || tempChr[i] == 1)
        {
            ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This would be a possible method. But as I said, not 100% sure.

Comment: Your code is not valid C++.

Comment: That's why I explained what it's supposed to do. I just wrote this without having something at hand to test it.